# Подключение к базе

Tags: mysql, php, хостинг

Здравствуйте, нужно подключиться к базе который находиться на другом хостинге, для этого соотвествено нужно знать хост, а где его взять? по адресу к базе я обращаюсь так http://*IP*:8081/phpmyadmin/ где воожу логин и пароль. но сайт не подключается к такому адресу

Answer (score 1):

Гдеж вы такое вычитываете?? Для подключения к базе необходимо знать:

1. IP адрес или hostname
2. порт
3. логин и пароль пользователя, которму разрешено подключаться к этому хосту.

Все подробности узнавайте у ответственного того хостинга, к которому хотите подлючиться. В большинстве случаев mysql не торчит наружу и пользователи не имеют возможности к ней подключаться.

Comment: Какое это такое? : ) то о чем я предположил вы и подтвердили, нужно IP порт логин и пароль : )

Буду узнавать точные адресса

Comment: > по адресу к базе я обращаюсь так http://*IP*:8081/phpmyadmin/ где воожу логин и пароль. но сайт не подключается к такому адресу

просто вот эта фраза мозг вынесла :)